# When using a combo box, is it possible to align the text in the center of the dropdown menu options?

Tags: javascript

When using a combo box, is it possible to align the text in the center of the dropdown menu options? Specifically, I want the text to appear centered within each option element when the user clicks on the combo box.

I am using the Foxit PhantomPDF program and created the combo box. The Foxit PhantomPDF program only lets you align text to the right or left. I want to know if you can align the text to be center aligned in the combo box using Javascript.

I tried to align using just one line of code:

```
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
```

The photo shows that the text is left aligned, but I want it to be centered in the middle.
[image: photo for understanding]

Comment: have you tried [this](https://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-phantompdf/169376-form-field-formatting-text-left-centre-or-right) (Manage Form Fields -> Properties/Options/Alignment. Center should apparently be in there?

Comment: Yes friend, it only has left and right alignment. I want to know if it is possible using the javascript script to align in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Foxit company and was informed that it is not possible. Has anyone been through this situation and managed to solve with some programming code or used a program?